# Android Studio: Show unmodified directory structure in the project view

Tags: android-studio

I have recently updated my Android Studio to 1.0.1 and dislike the new way it represents the project structure:

[image: project view - android studio 1.0]

How can I revert to the former arrangement where the unmodified filesystem directory layout is shown in the project view?

[image: project view - android studio 0.9]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look to your first screenshot. There is an android dropdown button. Click it and change your layout

Comment: Although comments like "thanks" are discouraged, I can not help myself. So, thanks!

Comment: @HamidFadishei have fun with the new/old project view ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm an idiot but after reading the accepted answer it still took me a long time to find it.

You need to click `Android ▼` located in the top left of the `Project` panel.

The option is *not* in the gear menu `⚙` to the right (which I wasted a long time looking at).

[image: Project View in Android Studio]

Once you have clicked `Android ▼` you should see a set of options as shown in the screenshot above. Select `Project`.